# yui child selector

Tags: javascript, yui3

I have a two divs which have class name "container". Each of this divs contain equal no. of children. I want to assign a class to nth child of each container. How can I do this using YUI3

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child selected"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child selected"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by iterating through each parent and then manipulate its children:

```
YUI().use('node', function(Y){
    Y.all('.container').each(function(elt) {
        elt.all('.child').item(1).removeClass('selected');
        elt.all('.child').item(2).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Just change item(N) to whatever number you need. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DS3dy/8/